# Why will the new button column that I added not show up after I have added it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, buttonfield, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

Follow up from a previous question I have made: [Getting and error I cannot fix when trying to add a button column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46063385/getting-and-error-i-cannot-fix-when-trying-to-add-a-button-column)

After making the aforementioned corrections given by the accepted answer, my code will now build successfully.  However, neither the column header or the buttons will show up.  Is there someplace I should be adding the column specifically?  My code for generating the table looks like such:

```
void LoadDataTable()
    {
        //create table
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        AddColumnToTable(table);

        //query all students
        IQueryable<Member> query = from mem in SLHS_DB.Members
                                       where mem.RoleId == (int)Credentials.MemberRole.STUDENT
                                       select mem;

        Member[] students = query.ToArray();

        //add them to table
        curStudentIndex = 0;

        foreach (Member student in students)
        {
            AddRowToTable(table, student);
        }


        //bind data to grid view
        gridViewStudent.DataSource = table;
        gridViewStudent.DataBind();

        var btn = new ButtonField();
        btn.HeaderText = "Click Data";
        btn.Text = "Click Here";

        gridViewStudent.Columns.Add(btn);
    }
```

And the part where I attempt to add a column of buttons are the last few lines.  I have tried adding a new column beforehand in the local function AddColumnToTable():

```
void AddColumnToTable(DataTable table)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(NUMBER    , typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add(FIRSTNAME , typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add(LASTNAME  , typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add(AGE       , typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add(EMAIL     , typeof(string));

        //table.Columns.Add(EDIT      , typeof(ButtonField));
    }
```

where the commented part was what I tried, but it made no impact.

Comment: `gridViewStudent.DataSource` & `gridViewStudent.DataBind` should be placed after `gridViewStudent.Columns.Add` in `RowDataBound` event. In which event that `AddColumnToTable` & `LoadDataTable` method bounds to?

Comment: Are you saying that I should re-order then in the way you mentioned and then put them in the function that generates the rows?  Also I am not sure what you mean by which events AddColumnToTable and LoadDataTable are bounded to.  They should just automatically start up generating the table as soon as I load the web page that it is on correct?

Comment: I think you're adding `ButtonField` after the data binding with `DataBind` which doesn't makes sense (try reordering with `DataBind` at last). What I want to find out is in which `GridView` event that both 2 methods above was called (`RowDataBound`, `Init`, `Load` or event methods like that).

Comment: Could it possible be this?

    **protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckMember();
            LoadDataTable();
        }**                                               Sorry about the formatting I am not sure how to format code in comments

Comment: Yes, the `Page_Load` method matches as one of the event methods I said before. I think you can't add a `ButtonField` into `DataTable` - it accepts only value types & strings, `ButtonField` instance must be added separately in `RowDataBound` or `GridView` column-related event methods.

Comment: So then which event must I put it in if not into a Load event?  Shouldn't I want this column to load once the page is loaded?

Comment: You can try creating `ButtonField` in `RowDataBound` event if `Load` event binding doesn't work. Your problem seems similar to these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229127/add-gridview-button-dynamically & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839399/how-to-store-buttonfield-in-a-datarow-where-the-column-is-set-for-buttonfield (note the use of `TemplateField`).